# pythonian module import with relative path

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with Python module paths.

I have following directory structure with 3 Python files:

```
a.py
b/c.py
b/d.py
```

That is a.py and in directory b files c.py and d.py. File contents are as follows:

## a.py:

```
from b.c import C
from b.d import D

def A():
    C()
    D()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A()
```

## c.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from d import D
else:
    from .d import D

def C():
    print('C')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    C()
    D()
```

## d.py:

```
def D():
    print('D')
```

I want to be able to run a.py in its own directory as 'python3 a.py' and run c.py with 'python3 c.py' in b as current directory.

The above code works as I want and outputs C and D in both cases.

But I wonder if there is a better and more pythonian way of resolving the import D in file c.py?

The first import works if I run c.py as main and the second import works if I run a.py as main.

I have tried all kinds of manipulations of the sys.path without success.

Comment: "I have tried all kinds of manipulations of the sys.path without success." That's a terrible idea in general...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a structure like

```
a.py
b/__init__.py
b/c.py
b/d.py
```

and the contents

### a.py

```
from b.c import C
from b.d import D

def A():
    C()
    D()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A()
```

### b/c.py

```
from .d import D

def C():
    print('C')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    C()
    D()
```

## b/d.py

```
def D():
    print('D')
```

you can use all of these:

- `python a.py` (just a standard script; working directory on sys.path)
- `python -m b.c` (`-m` for "run module"; working directory on sys.path but entry point set up to be a module)
- `python -m b.d` (same as above, though it does nothing)

You *can't* easily and sanely make `python b/c.py` work in this scenario, and you shouldn't try since `python -m b.c` works just fine.

Comment: Actually my original question asked how I can run c.py when in directory b but your suggestion of running it from the parent directory as 'python -m b.c' is an acceptable solution for me. Thanks for this suggestion that I did not think of myself.

Comment: I know, but there is no good way of doing what you originally asked, hence this method.

Comment: As an additional thought I think python's way of finding modules and the limitations of import paths are pretty weird. Why cannot I freely specify import paths up and down the file hierarchy?

I have another project where my directory structure looks like this and I cannot change it because it is decided by external factors:
<br>
- a: c.py
|
- b: d.py
<br>
2 parallel directories a and b and c.py in a and d.py in b.
How can I import d from c.py without manipulating the sys.path?

Comment: `from a.c import d` works just fine in that situation.